# Mixed date column

Tags: r

I am trying to format 2 date columns to be formatted as dates instead of date formatted and excel formatted.

An example of what I'm inputting would be:

```
DateAssigned <- c("02/20/2024","45338","45337","02/16/2024")
df <- data.frame(DateAssigned)
```

What I am trying to attain is:

```
DateAssigned
------------
02/20/2024
02/16/2024
02/15/2024
02/16/2024
```

I have attempted something like this but its making every date 1970-01-01 instead of just changing the number to a date format.

```
df$DateAssigned=as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character(df$DateAssigned)),origin="1970-01-01")
```

Comment: @r2evans syntax errror. Fixed it and then the question got closed.

Comment: Code adapted from the dupe link: `dates <- as.Date(DateAssigned, format = "%m/%d/%Y"); nas <- is.na(dates); dates[nas] <- as.Date(as.integer(x[nas]), origin="1900-01-01")`, now see that the `dates` object has all of these properly interpreted and a `Date`-class object.

Comment: Yes, I closed the question because this is a perfect duplicate. Just change the variable names, and the other answer's code works (adapted into my previous comment here).

Comment: If _this_ code doesn't work with all of your real data, and the _other_ linked answer doesn't help with the use of "candidate formats", then edit your question and @-ping me, I'll take a look.

Comment: @r2evans running that code even on the `DateAssigned` vector yields `[1] "1900-01-01" "1900-01-02" "1900-01-02" "1900-01-01"` which is where I get running the code in my question.

Comment: Oops, `x` slipped in there. Try `dates <- as.Date(DateAssigned, format = "%m/%d/%Y"); nas <- is.na(dates); dates[nas] <- as.Date(as.integer(DateAssigned[nas]), origin="1900-01-01")`, which for me returns `structure(c(19773, 19771, 19770, 19769), class = "Date")` (aka `as.Date(c("2024-02-20", "2024-02-18", "2024-02-17", "2024-02-16"))`)